# How do you dynamically change the asset input in a pipeline?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-pipelines

In AzureML, I have a pipeline that takes in a data asset. The pipeline is now published and I'd like to change that data asset. How do you do that? There don't seem to be docs for this, but from the `requests` response I've gathered it should be something like this:

```py
my_asset = ml_client.data.get('awesomeAsset', '1')

requests.post(
    pipe_endpoint,
    headers=headers,
    json={
        "ExperimentName": "test2211",
        "RunSource": "SDK",
        "DataSetDefinitionValueAssignments": {
            "userdefined_file": {
                "AssetDefinition": {
                    "Path": my_asset.path,
                    "Type":0,
                    "AssetId": my_asset.id
                    
                }
            }
        },
        "ParameterAssignments": {"deployment_name": "taco1121"}
        }
```

This throws `"Error converting value \\"/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/sd-{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace}/data/{name}/versions/{version}\\" to type "Microsoft.MachineLearning.Common.Core.AssetId"` and gives 400 bad request. Now, if I leave out the "AssetDefinition" and use the default file that was submitted I see that the AssetId sets as `"azureml://locations/westus2/workspaces/{wokspace}/data/{run id}/versions/{version}"`

It seems that `my_asset.id` doesn't yield the correct id, so what is the correct id and how do I access it, especially if I don't have a run id since the data was uploaded through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `my_asset.id` isn't interpretable, but I figured out the format for how to pass it.

If you give AssetId the value `azureml://locations/{location}/workspaces/{workspace_id}/data/{data_name}/versions/{data_version}` then you can properly change the data asset of a published pipeline.